# How to detect phone number on multiline using Regex?

Tags: regex

I use this regular expression to detect 10 digits phone number:

`/[0-9]{10}|[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{7}/gs`

It detects things like: `050-1231231`, `0501231231` and even: `050` and `1231231`

I would like to detect the number even if it's across 10 lines like so:

```
0

5

0

1

2

3

1

2

3

1
```

Comment: Add an optional whitespace match, like `(?:[0-9](?:\s*)?){10}`. Don't use the dot. It'll match 11 digits too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
/\d(?:\W*\d){9}/g
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/F319fw/2).

**NOTE**

If phone number is meant replace `\W` with `[-+()\s]`, and/or add any other characters you see in your phone numbers.

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (9 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \W*                      non-word characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-
                             9, _) (0 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){9}                     end of grouping
```

Comment: That'll also match "1%%%%2,,,,/*34567891"

Comment: @Scratte What makes you think it is not a valid case here? Neither `-` nor linefeed are numeric.

Comment: I'm thinking it's not a valid phone number :)

Comment: @Scratte Added a note, thanks.